Pressing another key interrupts timer/script when waiting for certain key pressed conditions
I'm a noob, so this might look ugly and could probably be improved.
The script below does the following:

When capslock is activated and
Spacebar is pressed down
Submit a space every 10ms

This works as intended UNTIL another key (lets say 'e') is pressed while holding spacebar. Even after 'e' is let go, the script does not resume sending spaces. Ideally, so long as space is being pressed, it would continue sending spaces regardless if another key is pressed.
The script:
#Singleinstance
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

A_MaxHotkeysPerInterval := 2000 ;
TimerActive := false

CheckCapsAndSpace() {
    global TimerActive
    ; Check if Caps Lock is active and Space is held down
    if GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T") && GetKeyState("Space", "P") {
        ; Start sending space keystrokes every 100ms if the conditions are met
        if !TimerActive {
            TimerActive := true
            SetTimer(SendSpace, 10) ; Set a 10ms interval for sending space
        }
    } else if TimerActive {
        ; Stop sending space if conditions are no longer met
        SetTimer(SendSpace, 0)
        TimerActive := false
    }
}

SendSpace() {
    Send(" ")
}

SetTimer(CheckCapsAndSpace, 10) ; Run the CheckCapsAndSpace function every 10ms to check conditions

You can easily test this by opening Notepad and modifying the Send call to Send(" s")

Maybe this is what you're trying to do... I just modified the script to monitor when the space key is released. Aside from this parameter and Caps Lock being active, it will keep sending space whenever the space key is pressed. I also removed the persistent check, so it only activates when space has been pressed and not released, as the script requires space to be pressed to execute.
#Singleinstance
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
A_MaxHotkeysPerInterval := 2000
SpaceHeld := false
 
~Space::
{
    global SpaceHeld := true
    CheckCapsAndSpace()
    Return
}

; Monitor when Space is released
Space Up::
{
    global SpaceHeld := false
    CheckCapsAndSpace()
    Return
}

CheckCapsAndSpace() {
    global SpaceHeld
    if GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T") && SpaceHeld
        SetTimer(SendSpace, 10)
    else if !SpaceHeld
        SetTimer(SendSpace, 0)
}

SendSpace() {
    If !GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T")
        Return
    Send(" ")
}


I'm having an issue where Space Up does not trigger and gets stuck until I manually hit space. Any idea?

If you hold down the space key for too long (due to the short 10ms delay), it will queue the send(" ") commands and will only detect Space Up when all send(" ") commands have been sent. To resolve this, you can replace the CheckCapsAndSpace() and the return with a single reload within Space Up, so the script will reload when the space key is released, ending any existing queue.

With the help of Dieisson and the folks over at AHK Discord, the issue with space getting stuck was the SendMode. Changed Send to SendEvent solved the issue.
Simplified:
#Singleinstance
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

A_MaxHotkeysPerInterval := 2000
SetKeyDelay -1, 0

#HotIf GetKeyState('CapsLock', 'T')
$Space:: {
    Static sendSpace := () => SendEvent(' ')
    SetTimer(SendSpace, 10), SendSpace()
    KeyWait 'Space'
    SetTimer(SendSpace,  0)
}
#HotIf

